# Need to type rvm use everytime I open rails project folder

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-5, rvm

Although my projects in Rails have .ruby-version setup, everytime I open a project I need to use: rvm use 'ruby version'

This happens since last osx update and I cannot figure out any workaround.

My rvm list:

```
 rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

My .ruby-version file on one ot he projects:

```
 cat .ruby-version
ruby-2.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I forgot to say that my projects runs also with gemsets. The problem was that somehow osx update messed up with the gemsets. Solution was to delete the gemset and return to build it.